# Modify an object's method from outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, object

I'm trying to modify the functionality of res.render method in express.
By default, the res.render method takes a template as it's first  argument, optional object as a second argument, and an optional function as its third.
I want that whenever res.render is called, it will always excute some code alongisde the third function that is provided (if any, but the default code should be executed regardless).

So I tried doing:

```
  router.use((req, res, next) => {
    let foo = res.render;
    function bar(layout, options, func) {
      foo(layout, options, funcWithExtraCode(res, func));
      //func with extra code returns a function for normal behaviour
    }
    res.render = bar;
    next();
  });
```

but i'm getting an error when doing so:

> (node:1104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'req' of undefined
> at render (C:\Users\Yogesh Bhatt\Desktop\chat-app-website\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:990:18)
> at ServerResponse.bar [as render] (C:\Users\Yogesh Bhatt\Desktop\chat-app-website\routes\first-level.js:25:7)
> at C:\Users\Yogesh Bhatt\Desktop\chat-app-website\routes\chat.js:24:9
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

So I believe I'm doing something wrong while copying the funciton. And from what I know, funciton or objects in JavaScript do not get copied, but rather referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `foo()` is not the same as calling the original `res.render()` because `this` inside of `foo` will NOT be set to `res` and the original implementation of `render()` needs to access `res` from `this`.

There are several ways you can fix it.  Here's one:

```
  router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.foo = res.render;
    function bar(layout, options, func) {
      res.foo(layout, options, funcWithExtraCode(res, func));
      //func with extra code returns a function for normal behaviour
    }
    res.render = bar;
    next();
  });
```

Or, you could use `.call()` to explicitly set the `this` value to what it's supposed to be:

```
  router.use((req, res, next) => {
    let foo = res.render;
    function bar(layout, options, func) {
      foo.call(res, layout, options, funcWithExtraCode(res, func));
      //func with extra code returns a function for normal behaviour
    }
    res.render = bar;
    next();
  });
```